# Impresspages ugly hash tag in address bar

Tags: impresspages

I wish to know what is the purpose of these ugly has tag at the end of every link in the address bar of a Impresspages 4.x website. How can I remove them from Impresspages front side website...

Comment: Can you give an example (link to a website)? I have a feeling that you have some social sharing option on your website and those plugin does that to track clicks and other user actions. Just to confirm - ImpressPages core has nothing to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean slash " **/** "

this tag was added to improve the speed for running website on apache,

for delete this option you can going to config -> advanced options -> then remove "Add trailing slash at the end of page URL"

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about something like this http://yourwebpage.com/contact/#.VMw7dftwbs0 just look for **AddThis** or another social plugin and deactivate it in admin->Plugins.
This should remove hashtag from URLs.